# How do i sort the following list of dictonaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

A single dictionary consists of `3` `key:value` pairs and I need to sort the dictionaries by comparing the first key, if the value is same the compare the second key and so on, how do I do it?

For example , if the list of dictionaries is as follows:

```
lst = [{'a':10,'b':20,'c':30},{'a':20,'b':50,'c':30},{'a':20,'b':40,'c':10},{'a':20,'b':40,'c':30}]
```

After sorting, result must be as follows:

```
[{'a':20,'b':50,'c':30},{'a':20,'b':40,'c':30},{'a':20,'b':40,'c':10},{'a':10,'b':20,'c':30}]
```

Here we can see, in the original list value of key `'a'` of last `3` dictionaries was same, therefore we compared the `'b'` key of them and sorted them accordingly, but `'b'` key of last 2 dictionaries was same therefore we compared the `'c'` key and applied the sort.

Comment: the dicts in your example have 3 key:value pairs, not 4. And you know that before 3.7 dicts are unordered, i.e. first, second, etc. key is ambiguous, right?

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html), taking the dictionary's `values` in the `key` function, that way the sorting will take place according to all values in each dictionary:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: list(x.values()), reverse=True)

[{'a': 20, 'b': 50, 'c': 30},
 {'a': 20, 'b': 40, 'c': 30},
 {'a': 20, 'b': 40, 'c': 10},
 {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]
```